# Error al utilizar un URL con LibCurl C++. No se puede resolver el host name o el URL es inválido

Tags: c++, api, curl

estoy realizando una pequeña implementación en C++. La idea principal es consultar una API y obtener un parámetro de configuración.
A modo de ejemplo estoy utilizando la API "PokeAPI".
Al hacer la implementación con el dato del url hardcodeado no tengo problema.
Mi problema ocurre cuando obtengo el dato desde el .ini del programa.
Cuando uso el url del .ini, los errores que me aparecen son:
"No se puede resolver el host name" o "el URL es inválido".
Esto contiene el .ini:
[API]
URL=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/
Con comillas simples o dobles, me trae el mismo resultado y en los cout puedo ver que lo está trayendo bien.
Paso los dos ejemplos que estoy haciendo, el primero es el que funciona y el segundo el que no:

```
int Application::run()
{
int result;
string url = "a";
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

CURL* contexto = curl_easy_init();
if (contexto == NULL) {
    cerr << "Unable to initialize cURL interface" << endl;
    return 1;
}

 //La url objetivo
result = this->loadConfiguration();
if (result != SUCCESS) {
    return result;
}
else {
    url = this->configuration.getAPIURL();
}
cout << url <<endl;
cout << this->configuration.getAPIURL()<<endl;
curl_easy_setopt(contexto, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/");
//funciona
//curl_easy_setopt(contexto, CURLOPT_URL, url); 
// no funciona

curl_easy_setopt(contexto, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);

curl_easy_setopt(contexto, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, stderr);

curl_easy_setopt(contexto, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, stdout);
curl_easy_setopt(contexto, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5L); /* 5 seconds timeout */

const CURLcode rc = curl_easy_perform(contexto);

if (CURLE_OK != rc) {
    cerr << "Error from cURL: " << curl_easy_strerror(rc) << endl;
}
else {
    // Estudiar algunos parómetros de la respuesta
    cout << "\n\n **STATS** \n\n" << endl;
    double valorDouble;
    long valorLong;
    char* valorChar = NULL;
    if (CURLE_OK == curl_easy_getinfo(contexto, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, &valorLong)) {
        cout << "Codigo de Respuesta:  " << valorLong << endl;
    }

    if (CURLE_OK == curl_easy_getinfo(contexto, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &valorChar)) {
        cout << "Tipo de Contenido:   " << valorChar << endl;
    }

    if (CURLE_OK == curl_easy_getinfo(contexto, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD, &valorDouble)) {
        cout << "Bytes Descargados:  " << valorDouble << "bytes" << endl;
    }

    if (CURLE_OK == curl_easy_getinfo(contexto, CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD, &valorDouble)) {
        cout << "Velocidad de Descarga: " << valorDouble << "bytes/sec" << endl;
    }

}
//Limpiar contexto y el sistema de libcurl
curl_easy_cleanup(contexto);
curl_global_cleanup();

return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno luego de buscar un poco más, en la documentación de Curl encontré lo siguiente y solucionó mi inconveniente:

"If you use libcurl from a C++ program, it is important to remember that you cannot pass in a string object where libcurl expects a string. It has to be a null terminated C string. Usually you can make this happen with the c_str() method."

Es decir, agregué .c_str() en mi cadena y quedó funcionando así:

```
curl_easy_setopt(contexto, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```